# Connect to RethinkDB with TLS

Tags: ssl, rethinkdb, tls1.2

I'm trying to add TLS to a node application connecting to RethinkDB database. I've setup the RethinkDB to use --driver-tls* parameter.

The strange thing to me is that on the client side I need to provide the CA certificate use to sign the certificates used by the server.

Is that root CA certificate can be self-signed or does it have to be signed with a trusted root CA itself?